# AWS Lambda AP Gateway Handling DIfferent Routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, gateway

I have 3 webhooks that calls my API Gateway which calls my Lambda Function.

1. url/webhook/....

I want each webhook to call its own python method

```
 startDelivery --> def start_delivery(event, context):
 UpdateStatus--> def update_status(event, context):
 EndDelivery--> def end_delivery(event, context):
```

I understand most likely one method will be executed via "url/webhook" which calls the appropriate python method.
`def Process_task` to call one of the three

What is the ideal way to set up this structure?

Creating different urls for Webhooks and API Gateway captures it and somehow calls the handler?

```
url/webhook/start
url/webhook/status
url/webhook/end
```

Sending a different query string for each webhook? and in the lamba parse the query string and call the right python method?

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that a Lambda function has one handler (=> 1 invocation = 1 method called).

You can achieve the 1 route <-> 1 method by doing one of the following:

1. You have a single Lambda function triggered by your 3 APIGW routes.
   You can then add a simple router to your function which parse the `event['path']` and call the appropriate method.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   path = event['path']

   if path == '/webhook/start':
       return start_delivery(event, context)
   elif path == '/webhook/status':
       return update_status(event, context)
   elif path == '/webhook/end':
       return end_status(event, context)
   else:
       return { "statusCode": 404, "body": "NotFound" }
```

2. Create 1 Lambda function by route:

- webhook/start triggers the StartDelivery Lambda function with start_delivery as handler
- webhook/status triggers the UpdateDelivery Lambda function with update_delivery as handler
- webhook/end triggers the EndDelivery Lambda function with end_delivery as handler

You can use Infrastructure as Code (Cloudformation) to easily manage these functions (SAM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html)

Answer (score 1):

acorbel's answer was helpful for me. The latest version is Format 2.0. Many fields have changed. For example event['path'] doesn't exist with Format 2.0.
Please check the below link for correct key names of event structure.

[Working with AWS Lambda proxy integrations for HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html)